# Varnish Error Log Files

Tags: linux, web-server, logging, varnish

I upgraded to version 4.1 from 4.0 and everything was working fine until I restarted the service and it shows Starting or Started, but when I check the status or go to a website the services shows stopped and I cannot access any of my web sites. With some Google'in I was able to get the access log going, but I cannot find how to get a log going of what happens when I go to start the Varnish service. If there is no way to log service start errors from Varnish what log should I use to figure out the issue of the service starting then stopping right away? System: CentOS 6, Varnish 4.1.0, I upgraded via the package manager.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably run strace (signal trace) to see where exactly it fails. strace /etc/init.d/varnishd start should provide some helpful information.